# replacing the command after execution gives NA in the datasheet?

Tags: r

I am currently learning R and used the function `factor()`. After executing the code

```
factor(dataset$Purchased, levels = c('Yes', 'No'), labels = c(1, 2))
```

I changed the code to

```
factor(dataset$Purchased, levels = c('Yes', 'No'),labels = c(1, 0))
```

Now the column `Purchased` in the datasheet is showing NA

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Could you please make your question a bit more clear and provide a bit more source code? Thank you!

Comment: What does dataset$Purchased look like before you call factor()? That behavior looks like the levels you are specifing are not present in the incoming vector